# MVC 3 decimal server-side validation problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I´m using JQuery Unobtrusive validation... I´m configured with Globalize to accept numbers like that : 1.500,50 (Masked by JQuery)

My code so far

1- ) Configured Globalize

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
};

$(function () {
    Globalize.culture('pt-BR');
});
```

2-) Configured web.config

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

Ok, so I´m using a JQuery plugin to format Textbox to Money(PT-BR) like that : 1.500.000,50...

My JQuery Client Validation is working fine! But when it goes to server validation I got a ModelState error:

```
"The value '1.500.000,50' is not valid for Total."
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of a format is this? with two decimals rather than one?

Comment: the '.' is for thousands and ',' for decimal part ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem in MVC binding to values like that. Go through [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx) by Phil Haack. It shows you how to create a cusom model binder to handle this.

Comment: Thanks... I already read that... And for some odd reason my DecimalModelBinder are never called... I dont konw why, I follow exactly like Phil Haack described... Only difference I´m using S#arp Architeture...

Comment: @Paul does `S#arp Architeture` add custom binders? I haven't gone through the source code.

Comment: It has on Global.asax :  ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new SharpModelBinder();

Comment: @Paul either yo'll have to remove that line or modify `SharpModelBinder` to use the custom model binder for `decimal`

Comment: Is there a solution for mvc6?